# Auto extending width of float-left div next to a fixed-width float-right div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I basically have two divs (div2 and div3) in a containing div1. div2 floats left and div3 floats rights. Div3 is fixed width while div2 ***should*** auto-extend up to div3. The problem I seem to be having is, while the content in div2 auto extends to 100% of div2 (the input box), div2 itself does not auto-extend to div3; I have no idea why it's not working the way I expect. In contrast, if I set div2 to width:100% it ends up pushing div2 down; this makes sense to me though.

I expect something like this:

```
------------div1--------------
[--------div2----------][div3]
-----------/div1--------------
```

I've been banging my head at this, trying float:right, float: left, clear:right,  pull-left, pull-right in bootstrap and nothing seems to work as I want.

I was going to use bootstraps columns to automatically resize but the requirement is that div3 must always be the same size regardless of screen size.

Here is my simple [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yNHG4/) example. Can anyone please point me to the problem? I have a sense the answer is staring at me in the face.

Accompanying code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <style>
    body {
        min-height: 2000px;
        background-color: #EEE;
    }

    a:focus { outline: 0;}

    .tab-content {background-color: #f9f9f9;}

    #maintab .active a { background-color: #f9f9f9;}


    #page1SearchBox{
        float:left;
        margin-right: 80px;
        width:auto;
        overflow: auto;
    }
    .searchBoxContainer {
        position: relative;
    }
    .searchBoxContainer .searchBoxIcon {  
        padding-left: 5px; 
        padding-top:6px; 
        position: absolute;
    }

    .searchBoxContainer .searchQuery { 
        border: 1px solid #ddd; 
        width: 100%; 
        padding-left: 25px; 
        height:30px;
    }

    #page1DropDown{
        float:right;
        width: 80px;
    }
    #page1DropDownMenu{
        width: 100%;
    }

    #page1DropDownListButtonGroup{
        width: 100%;
    }

    .page1Container{
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="tab-content case-tab-content">
            <div id="page1" class="tab-pane active">
                <div id="page1Container">
                    <div>
                        <div id="page1SearchBox">
                            <div class="searchBoxContainer">
                                <div class="searchBoxIcon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></div>
                                <div class="searchBoxInput"><input class="searchQuery text-muted" type="text" placeholder="Search"></input></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="page1DropDown">
                            <div class="btn-group" id="page1DropDownListButtonGroup">
                                <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="page1DropDownMenu" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                    %
                                    <span class="caret"></span>
                                </button>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right" role="menu" aria-labelledby="page1DropDownMenu">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div style="clear:right;"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--Load 3rd party first-->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that JSFiddle is down, so I'm not able to see your example code. But if I am understanding the issue correctly one possible solution could be to use the CSS3 calc() function (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc). It allows you to mix percentage and fixed-pixel values on-the-fly.

```
.div2 { 
    float: left;
    width: calc(100% - 300px);
}
.div3 { 
    float: left;
    width: 300px; 
}
```

Note that this is classified as experimental will not work in IE8 or below (http://caniuse.com/calc).

Comment: This is really cool, thanks! This is a new app so the team decided that anything lower than IE9 will not be supported anyway.